# Can a non-store Office Add-In display Licence Terms when deployed in Admin Center?

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing an Outlook Add-In for enterprise customers that they will be hosting themselves, so I assume the best method for deployment is by using [using the Admin Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/manage-deployment-of-add-ins?view=o365-worldwide#deploy-an-office-add-in-using-the-admin-center) to deploy a custom Add-In.

When deploying a Store Add-In, the Admin can be prompted to accept licence terms and view the Add-In's privacy policy.
[image: License terms and Privacy Policy prompt]

Is it also possible for a custom add-in to show a prompt like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible for a custom add-in today to show a License + Privacy Policy prompt.

We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.